# oracle 10g get all selected columns and datatype from a single select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get all selected columns from a single select statement without performing the execution . The query may use join or union , then the query may consist more than just one table , so I can not simply use the statement

```
select column_name, data_type
from user_tab_cols
where table_name = 'my_table_name'
```

to get the result .

For example

**input:**

```
select db1.*
  from (select dept_code,
               vital_signs,
               units,
               log_time
          from table1
         where dept_code = '111'
        union
        select 'hl06' as dept_code,
               vital_signs,
               units,
               log_time
          from table2
         where isdefault = 1
           and vital_signs not in
               (select vital_signs
                  from Ward_Vs_Vital_Signs
                 where dept_code = '111')) db1,
       table3 db2
 where db1.vital_signs = db2.vital_signs(+)
 order by db2.serial_no
```

**output:**

```
column_name  | data_type
-------------------------
dept_code    | VARCHAR 
vital_signs  | NUMBER
units        | VARCHAR
log_time     | DATE
```

My question is how can I parse the query and ask the database to tell me the columns and data types that will be returned without executing the statement ? Thanks !

PS: I'm using Oracle 10g .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy way to do it using a single select statement, however, you can look into `dbms_sql` approach ([DOC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm#i997238)).

```
    14:32:26 SYSTEM@dwal> ed
Wrote file S:\spool\dwal\BUFFER_SYSTEM_329.sql

  1  DECLARE
  2    c           NUMBER;
  3    d           NUMBER;
  4    col_cnt     INTEGER;
  5    rec_tab     DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
  6    col_num    NUMBER;
  7    PROCEDURE print_rec(rec in DBMS_SQL.DESC_REC) IS
  8    BEGIN
  9      DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;
 10      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col_name            =    ' || rec.col_name);
 11      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col_type            =    ' || rec.col_type);
 12    END;
 13  BEGIN
 14    c := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
 15    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(c, 'SELECT dummy, 12345 num, sysdate dt FROM dual', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
 16    d := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(c);
 17    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(c, col_cnt, rec_tab);
 18    col_num := rec_tab.first;
 19    IF (col_num IS NOT NULL) THEN
 20      for i in 1 .. col_cnt LOOP
 21        print_rec(rec_tab(i));
 22      END LOOP;
 23    END IF;
 24    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c);
 25* END;
14:32:46 SYSTEM@dwal> /
col_name            =    DUMMY
col_type            =    1
col_name            =    NUM
col_type            =    2
col_name            =    DT
col_type            =    12

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Notice `col_type` numeric value above - it is a type code which maps to actual data type. The mapping is documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#i54330

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no option to find the datatype in the query. 
Instead you have to make a `create table as` or to `create view as` clause with the query and use then desc  or some data dictionaries like user_tab_cols.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you could use a PreparedStatement and the ResultSetMetaData it provides like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(yourSqlStatement);
ResultSetMetaData rsm = ps.getMetaData();
for(int i = 0; i<rsm.getColumnCount();i++) {
    int index = i+1;
    System.out.println(rsm.getColumnName(index) + ": " + rsm.getColumnTypeName(index));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Some questions like this had been asked before. Anyway I can post the answer.
Something like this might work:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM user_tab_cols
WHERE table_name = 'your_table_name'
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't address my question clearly . The table may come from a complex join statement , so I cannot get the "your table name" easily .